# What is the best vehicle platform to begin with (e.g. tracked, four-wheel drive)

Tags: sensors

Despite many articles on the topic of vehicle platforms, none of them seem to recommend the best one to start with. Later on I am sure I will seek an exact kind of chassis for autonomous vehicle construction, but now I am looking to learn the basics of this area of the Arduino world. If you could give me a simple recommendation for the general category of vehicle platform to use it would be much appreciated. I will be using an ultrasonic distance sensor coupled with a servo motor to detect obstacles, so it is a very simple project. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SparkFun's [Magician Chassis](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12866) is a very simple, very flexible chassis for starting out. Also comes as part of the [RedBot Kit](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12697).

[image]